# PHP Curl Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings

Tags: php, php-curl

I am faced with this problem when I send a request to this API that I bought via Rapid API.

Error : **Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.**

```
$curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://songstats.p.rapidapi.com/artists/info?spotify_artist_id=2h93pZq0e7k5yf4dywlkpM&songstats_artist_id=vxk62ige",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "X-RapidAPI-Host: songstats.p.rapidapi.com",
                "X-RapidAPI-Key: MY_API_KEY"
            ],
        ]);
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        
        curl_close($curl);
        
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
        exit;
```

`

I wanted to get the statistics of the artists after I made a request

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem, you can explicitly specify the accepted encodings in the cURL options. Simply add the line below to your cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
```

Here's the modified code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://songstats.p.rapidapi.com/artists/info?spotify_artist_id=2h93pZq0e7k5yf4dywlkpM&songstats_artist_id=vxk62ige",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate', // Explicitly set accepted encodings
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: songstats.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: MY_API_KEY"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
exit;
```

By setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to 'gzip, deflate', you're telling cURL that your client can handle responses compressed with either gzip or deflate encoding. This should resolve the issue you're facing with unrecognized content encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the problem persists and I continue to get the same error.